# How to get a parsed hexadecimal color string back for reuse?

Tags: android, parsing, kotlin

I try to get the parsed hexadecimal color string for use again in sharedpreferences in Kotlin. I mean:

```
editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E6000000"))
```

I want to get back this `#E6000000` as a string for using in saving and loading that color. How? I couldn't find any solution here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get back the `backgroundColor` you can use [ColorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable#summary) like so:

```
val backgroundColorDrawable = (editText.background as ColorDrawable)
```

now you will have to get the color:

```
val intColor = backgroundColorDrawable.color
```

since you want to use `Color.parse(String colorString)` again, you will have to format `intColor` to hex value that is acceptable by `Color.parseColor` which are:

```
#RRGGBB
#AARRGGBB
```

You can achieve this by `String.format()`:

```
val hexColor =  String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF  and intColor)
```

Comment: This method is more complex than I thought, anyway thank you for your help

Comment: Sure no problem, The idea is to get the color as an Int and to format it back to String that will be acceptable by Color.parse(), so you can take this idea and look up better solutions online, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to put the colors in the colors.xml resource file and then get the color by its id. 
Why do you need the string?

Comment: Because I have many colors, and using this parsecolor is much more cheaper than creating many xml files. And as I told on the post, I need to use that string for sharedpref